# Multitouch on a mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, browser

I have this browser game I'm developing for fun.

But I'm trying to make it work in mobile browsers too. But I can't seem to make it work when pressing multiple buttons at once.

I have this game where you can move left and right and jump. (see the picture below)

[image: touch buttons in game]
<sub>(source: [userhome.org](http://www.userhome.org/mobilegame.png))</sub>

My code looks like this:

```
function inittouchcontrols() {

$("body").append("<div id='btn_moveleft' keyid='37'></div><div id='btn_moveright' keyid='39'></div><div id='btn_jump' keyid='38'></div>");

    $('body').on('taphold', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('body').on('tap', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('body').on('vmouseover', function (e) {

        if($(e.target).attr("keyid") != undefined)
            $(e.target).css("background-color", "red");

        window["keyDown" + $(e.target).attr("keyid")]();

        c_key_x = c_key_left + c_key_right;
        c_key_y = c_key_up + c_key_down;

        $("#pushedkeys").html("keys: " + c_key_x + " " + c_key_y);

    });

    $('body').on('vmouseout', function (e) {

        if ($(e.target).attr("keyid") != undefined)
            $(e.target).css("background-color", "aqua");

        window["keyUp" + $(e.target).attr("keyid")]();

        c_key_x = c_key_left + c_key_right;
        c_key_y = c_key_up + c_key_down;


        $("#pushedkeys").html("keys: " + c_key_x + " " + c_key_y);

    });

}
```

I use jQuery mobile `vmouseover` and `vmouseout` to detect presses on the aqua colored divs. But it will only push one button at a time.

So my question is:
Is there any way I can implement multitouch to my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the touch event api touchstart, touchmove, and touchend (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Touch_events)

each will a touches collection, among other things, attached to it's event object.

One thing to note is that the touch properties aren't included in the normal jQuery event object so you have to use event.originalEvent to access them

```
$('#ele').on('touchstart', function(e) {
    var touches = e.originalEvent.touches;
});
```